# How to make div stay visible when hovering on it

Tags: html, css

I have a menu that contains a button, and if you hover on it a "popup" appears above it.
My problem is that i want the div to be visible if the user moves the mouse over to the "popup". Does anyone have some tips on how to continue? http://jsfiddle.net/c6fYt/

HTML

```
<div id="footer">
        <ul id="list">
            <li class="button">Button 1</li>
            <li class="box">AWBGBABBgehahnaphneaneihnahipneanpen</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#footer {
position:absolute;
bottom:1px;
width:100%;
min-width:800px;
height:50px;
background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
box-shadow:0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0) inset, 0px 10px 5px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) inset, 0px 35px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset;
}


#list {
list-style:none;
display:inline;
}

.button {/*box-shadow: h-shadow v-shadow blur spread color inset;*/
width:125px;
background-color:rgba(248, 248, 255, 0.25);
border-right:1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
margin:1px 0px 0px 0px;
padding:15px 0px;
text-align:center;
float:left;
color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0);
}

.button:hover {
background-color:rgba(248, 248, 255, 0.45);
}

.button:hover + .box {
display:block;
}

.box {
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
width:auto;
min-width:50px;
height:250px;
margin-top:-250px;
margin-left:-125px;
float:left;
display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
.button:hover + .box, .box:hover {
    display:block;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c6fYt/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in CSS only, because it will lose its visibility once it is not hovered anymore (if that is what I understood)

With only a few lines of JQuery, you can bypass this issue:

```
$('.button').hover(function()
{
    $('.box').show();
}
```

);

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/c6fYt/2/)

Comment: See Mooseman's answer on how you actually can quite simply do this with pure CSS.

Comment: Try his solution before commenting... It is not getting visible forever

Comment: I have and it works. Three other people seem to think so, too.

Comment: What OP wanted is just the ability to keep the grey menu box open when you move the cursor off of the button and on to the grey menu box itself. Just useful enough for something like putting more links in the aforementioned grey menu box :-)

Comment: oh okay, my fault then !